# Playing movie embedded in pdf-file in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, avi

Using LaTeX, I've created a pdf file, with an included movie (`.avi`). I've used this strategy a lot, and never had problems in playing the movie (after accepting to play it) inside Adobe Reader (10.1.6) on Windows 7 Starter.

Now I am trying this same approach on a different machine (simple netbook). The `.avi` movie properly plays with Windows Media Player and VLC-player outside the pdf document, and the relative path is correct. Now, when I click the movie to play it, it starts to load it for a while (~20MB movie), but it doesn't play and gives an error message

> Player software failed to play movie

I tried to change some of the Multimedia Settings, e.g.

- Multimedia (legacy) > Preferred Media Player. I tried all three options (Windows Media P layer, Windows Builtin, Adobe Flash
- 3D and Multimedia > Preferred Renderer. I tried Software and Direct X.

Non of these changed preferences were successful. How can I successfully play avi movies in my Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I discovered that the name of the folder, where the pdf was located, was not legal. When I change it, everything worked.